# PCA9306 Level Translator Output is coming without providing Enable Signal

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, i2c, level-shifting, level-translation

I am using PCA9306 board for level Translation .The schematic is given below.The board is purchased from third party not made by me.(https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15439)

I need to control the Enable pin using Arduino.

As the vendor suggested I cut the trace and filled the lower Jumper.

Vref_Low and Vref High are provided from Arduino.(3.3V and 5V).EN is also provided by Arduino and it is 5V

What I observed is

```
1)whether EN is high or LOW output is always coming.

2)Output voltage is not coming to 3.3V it is coming as 2.2V
```

May I know your thoughts.Is it the board issue or something wrong went from my side?
[image]

Comment: Ensure EN is actually being driven low (to 0V), and not being driven with an open collector output (which would be an indeterminate voltage).  Measure it with a scope or voltmeter, and report your observations.

Comment: Thank you.Without connecting anything to EN I observed a voltage of 2.8V or 3 at EN Pin.(Will confirm the values tomorrow)

Comment: Also, see the design requirements in 9.2.1 of the TI datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/pca9306 for proper voltage levels and Vref magnitude requirements.

Comment: Open circuit EN is indeterminate, and should be avoided.

Comment: May I know your thoughts about my observation-2

Comment: Nothing is reliable if EN is left Not Connected (open circuit), or not driven with a properly  designed circuit to 0 Volts (Ground) or VREF2.